# Does switch interract with port Forwading and DHCP?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, modem, wireless-access-point

Using currently a "BT Home Hub 5" for my network.

```
BT Hub 5 > Devices
```

I would like to change my network to

```
Modem > Switch > Devices
```

What would be the impact regarding DHCP and Port Forwarding ?

I would like to keep my current configuration

Given these requirements, would a bog-standard non-managed switch be insufficient?

Comment: Please accept the edition

Comment: @intika: edits automatically go into a review queue, no need to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the impact regarding DHCP and Port Forwarding ?

The DHCP server will be provided by your modem, and you will have to change the configuration on your new modem to match your old one.

> Port Forwarding ?

Port forwarding is available on modems but is disabled by default, you have to enable it on your new modem and edit the settings to match your current configuration.

> bog-standard non-managed switch be insufficient ?

A switch won't make a difference as it doesn't route your network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Business grade APs here I come...  No more consumer grade rubbish :D

Comment: glad it helped you :)